# Why is this XPath test against child text contents failing?

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is my example XML document:

```
<div class="firstlevel" id="firstid">
    <div class="secondlevel">
        <span class="thirdlevel">
            <a href="somelinknew">111 new</a>
            <span class="fourthlevel">222</span>
        </span>
        <span class="thirdlevel">
            <a href="somelinkold">333 old</a>
            <span class="fourthlevel">444</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this XPath:

```
//*[@class='thirdlevel' and //text()[contains(.,'new')]]/span
```

**But it returns both values, 222 and 444. Why?** I think the XPath is looking for "new" but show return also "old"?!

The main problem is, the code can also be like this:

```
<div class="firstlevel" id="firstid">
    <div class="secondlevel">
        <span class="thirdlevel">
            <a href="somelinkold">333 old</a>
            <span class="fourthlevel">444</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

or like this:

```
<div class="firstlevel" id="firstid">
    <div class="secondlevel">
        <span class="thirdlevel">
            <a href="somelinknew">111 new</a>
            <span class="fourthlevel">222</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

or just like this:

```
<div class="firstlevel" id="firstid">
    <div class="secondlevel">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//text()` is checking *all* text nodes in the document because `//` is checking self or descendents from the root level down.  Instead, just look for 'new' in the text starting from the current node, `.`, and descendents from *there*:

```
//*[@class='thirdlevel' and .//text()[contains(.,'new')]]/span
```

which can be simplified to

```
//*[@class='thirdlevel' and contains(.,'new')]/span
```

Comment: Ah, well, it was so easy and i was so close. Good to know that //text() checks all nodes. Haven't used it yet. Thanks!